# after job interview and initial offer not hearing back from recruiter

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, feedback

I had a phone interview, that moved into an in person. I had a questionnaire to fill and then the manager sent me an email to refill the questionnaire, which I did and replied with a thank you note. 2 days later I received a pre-offer to see if I would accept; he stressed that he was still going through some candidates he met the week before; I replied saying that I was very excited and that I had to questions (benefits and I had a week trip already schedule, if that would be possible to accommodate); he replied with the answer to the benefits and the nr of vacation weeks, also he would let me know soon. one week has passed and I don't know what that means and if I should follow up and how...any suggestions and/or insights? thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what a 'pre-offer' is, but it sounds like you are still in consideration for a position with this company.

It can't hurt anything at this point to reach out via phone or e-mail to inquire about where you stand.  Show them you are still interested!

Answer (score 0):

Unless your scheduled trip was for a good reason, like visiting family or birth of a niece/nephew etc, it is a hard hand to play, before getting hired. And it might have pushed you to the bottom of the heap. But at this stage it doesn't hurt to contact the manager.

As a rule of thumb, all recruiters say that, if you are being offered a permanent position, you do not start asking for 1. How much money you are going to get; 2. how many vacation days you will have; 3. If you can work from home. These questions are reserved after you had a foothold in the office. Otherwise, they reflect badly on your priorities. Every company will pay you (or offer you) a decent compensation, some vacation time (even though in the first couple of years, it won't be much) and every company has a written or unwritten work from home policy. But if you concentrate on these aspects when manager asked you the question of "if you had any questions for him", it might not be perceived as good.

Comment: I disagree that a scheduled trip is a hard hand to play. In my experience it is not unusual at all - I have several times started a new job with a trip already booked and had to bring it up whilst discussing their offer. Some companies will treat it as unpaid leave, others will allow you to go into a negative leave balance, but I've never heard of anyone having a serious issue with it.

Comment: @Carson63000 consider that every company hires a person when they needed it most if not later than when they need him or her due to bureaucratic red tape. If you throw another wrench into the wheel saying that you will be gone in a very short time for a week or two and they have another viable candidate, guess which one they will take. If you are only one in the game or they are staffing at a leisurely pace, yes, you are correct. That is my point.

Comment: "you do not start asking for 1. How much money you are going to get;" - Really? If this isn't actually told to you when the offer is being made, surely it's need-to-know information when considering whether to accept the offer... ?

Comment: A pre-scheduled trip is not that uncommon.  It has happened to me twice with no problems at all from the new employer.  Many vacations have to be booked and paid for months in advance, and it's not realistic to expect a new employee to throw that money away.  I wouldn't bring this up during an initial interview, but it needs to be discussed after you receive an offer to make sure everyone know what's going on.

Comment: "All recruiters" might say that (but I doubt it) because they make money placing people into positions, but you get to set your own priorities.